# Slope limiting for discontinuous Galerkin (DG) method

Tags: numerics, hyperbolic-pde, discontinuous-galerkin

I had a question regarding the implementation of the TVB limiter for the RKDG method by Cockburn.  I have seen that some implementations of the DG method use normalized Legendre polynomials such that the basis functions take the form

$$
\phi_{i}^{k}(x) = \sqrt{2k + 1}P^{k}(x).
$$

With this formulation, we have
$$
u_{h}(x) = \bar{u} + \sqrt{3} u_{x} \phi_{i}(x)
$$

Therefore we have a limited slope of the form

$$
s_{i}^{m} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \text{minmod} \left(\sqrt{3} u_{x}, \bar{u}_{i} - \bar{u}_{i-1}, \bar{u}_{i+1} - \bar{u}_{i}\right)
$$
However, I am using a non-normalized Legendre modal formulation.  As such, should'nt my limited slope just be

$$
s_{i}^{m} = \text{minmod} \left(u_{x}, \bar{u}_{i} - \bar{u}_{i-1}, \bar{u}_{i+1} - \bar{u}_{i}\right)?
$$

If I don't have the normalization constants my results are not correct.  I am currently validating my 1D solver on the famous Sod-Shock tube. As further details my system of equations with my DG formulation is of the form

$$
\frac{\Delta x}{2m + 1} \frac{d}{d t}  c_{i,m}(t)  -  \int_{\Omega_{i}} f\left( \sum_{m=0}^{k} c_{i,m}(t) \phi_{i,m}(x) \right) \frac{\partial \phi_{i,l}(x)}{\partial x} dx + \left[\hat{f} \left( \sum_{m=0}^{k} c_{i,m}(t) \phi_{i,m}(x)\right) \phi_{i,l}(x)\right]^{x_{i}}_{x_{i-1}} = 0, m = 0, \dots, k
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper of Cockburn and Shu [1] explains this. If the solution is
$$
u_h(x) = u_i + u_{xi} \phi(x), \qquad \phi(x) = \frac{x - x_i}{\Delta x/2}
$$
Then the limiter is
$$
u_{xi} = minmod(u_{xi}, u_i - u_{i-1}, u_{i+1}-u_i)
$$
Does your solution representation look as in the first equation above ?

Also, the solution with normalised Legendre basis will look like this
$$
u_h(x) = u_i +  u_{xi} \sqrt{3} \phi(x), \qquad \phi(x) = \frac{x - x_i}{\Delta x/2}
$$
Then the limiter is
$$
u_{xi} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} minmod(\sqrt{3}u_{xi}, u_i - u_{i-1}, u_{i+1}-u_i)
$$

[1] https://doi.org/10.1006/jcph.1998.5892

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I realized that the reason why I was getting wiggles in my solution was that I was applying the slope limiter to the conservative variables as opposed to applying the limiter to the characteristic variables.  I get very good results now.  As a side question, is there an advantage to applying the slope limiter to the primitive variables as opposed to the characteristic variables?

Comment: You could apply to primitive variables just as you do for characteristic variables. But there is some theoretical basis to limiting characteristic variables; you get TVD property at least in a linear case. The computational cost will be more or less same, so it seems good to limit characteristic variables.

Comment: Since your question is sort of answered, can you close this question.